# No signal Windows

Tags: windows

i have installed windows on my pc running on
Ryzen 5 5600G with integrated graphics
and have a monitor Acer AL2016W
so, when I'm first installed windows image was fine but i was unable to set resolution higher than 1024xSmth
so, when I'm installed drivers i got image with full resolution for little short time and then monitor showed up "no signal"

connected wia dvi-i (cannot connect vga cuz my motherboard has no, tried vga through hdmi to vga connector have a same problem)
in safe mode i have image

I'm tried to install monitor drivers manually
and 4~5 different versions of amd drivers from website, and one that windows installs automatically

Comment: How did you get a DVI cable to fit… spec says it's VGA only. HDMI>VGA is likely to only be good to 1080p. Monitors don't need drivers, graphics cards need drives, so that part is very unclear. Overall, you'd probably be better off sacking what was a low-end display even when new & buying something that will accept modern standards.

Comment: that monitor has both vga and dvi-i ports, I'm tried to use my tv with hdmi directly to my tv and it works fine. if I'd be able to buy new monitor rn i wouldn't be asking for help ;(